# What is the difference between using SEM and using mediation SEM on the same model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation

Hope you're doing well :)

With the following model: x --> m --> y, in which m could or could not be a mediator (this is one of the investigations' questions), is there a difference between performing a regular SEM where

y ~ m
m ~ x

and performing a mediation SEM where

y ~ c*x

y ~ b*m

m ~ a*x

?

I understand the theory of the mediation SEM, but still I cannot understand why determing m ~ x and y ~ m is not enough to ascertain mediation. Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SE! Would it be possible to specify where those informations come from? Some handbook maybe?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I am following this guide https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html from the lavaan package, and this other guide https://psu-psychology.github.io/r-bootcamp-2018/talks/lavaan_tutorial.html#testing-mediation. Both differentiate between regular SEM and mediation. For example, in the latter guide, they first test a SEM with rad > nox > cmedv, and then under the "testing mediation" section, they test the same rad > nox > cmedv pathway, but adding the a, b, c terms.